# How to remove/discard "free" ram usage in android app

Tags: android, eclipse, ram

I have an issue with RAM used by my app as it uses a lot of RAM. On diagnosing the usage I got a big shock seeing that more than half of ram is for nothing or say allocated free.. Here is preview

[image]

So I want to get rid of that burden on RAM which is nothing but free. I googled it but I think no good post on this issue..

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove all the free space in the heap, then you would an **OutOfMemoryError** the next instant.

Some space in the heap must always be free so that the OS can utilise to allocate memory as you keep running the app. If you remove all the free space, then the OS would not be able to allocate memory even to your variables and your application would crash due to OOM.

Instead of trying to free the empty space, you should ***focus on freeing the used space*** intelligently as when your move out of Activities. Make sure that there are no dangling references left in your Activities, as this leads to memory leaks and the heap size keeps on increasing until the system cant allocate any more and your application crashes. Try to remove references to images and remove any listener to callbacks if you have set any. Basically, try to reduce the memory footprint of the Activities.

An ideal state would be the Activity freeing up all the space it was using as soon as it is destroyed. For example, you have 1 byte array of 14 MB, which are basically Bitmaps stored in the memory because you might have left a reference to them somewhere.

Comment: Thank for your answer! and that are byte[] used by images but I got no way to remove or free up that memory. To best of my knowledge `byte[] anything = null;` dont clean up the reference (I mean heap still exist). If you got any way to do that, It will be appreciated...

Comment: I usually do it by assigning null to the ImageView holding the Bitmap in onDestroy(). That removes the reference to the Bitmap and the system can clean up the space while doing GC.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your heap expands as you allocate memory, if the heap does not have a block big enough for your allocation and your heap is smaller than the heap size limit for the device that you are on.

The heap *can* shrink, but particularly prior to Android 5.0, it is unlikely to shrink much. The heap expands by pages (4K?). The garbage collector will release memory back to the OS only when an entire page is free. However, Dalvik does not have a "moving", or compacting, garbage collector, and so it is only by sheer luck that a page ever becomes completely free of objects.

[ART has a moving garbage collector](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/06/16/art-garbage-collection.html), when your app is not in the foreground, and so it will be more prone to release memory back to the OS.

As Swayam suggests, all you can really do is make sure that you are using your heap efficiently. What the Android framework does with respect to managing your heap itself is up to the framework, and you cannot directly control it.